# Iterate and update values in a map

Tags: dart

I have a `map` called `oldMap` with generics `Map<String, List<int>>`. I need to replace all the values in the `oldMap`. I have `newValues` with is off type `List<List<int>>` for each value. The keys will be the same. But need a way to iterate through  newValues and add to the keys making a new `map`.

eg

```
oldMap = {'2': [14],'4': [11],'6': [2]}

newValues = [[11], [12], [19] ]// These values need to be in new map

newMap = {'2': [11],'4': [12],'6': [19]}
```

Comment: How do you decide which indices of `newValues` are assigned to which keys in `oldMap`? I'm guessing it's by sorting the keys of the map in ascending order, but just to be sure

Comment: Yes. Should of stated that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to replace the values in the existing key order, you can do:

```dart
var newMap = Map.fromIterables(oldMap.keys, newValues);
```

If you need some other key order, you need to figure out which, and then do something like:

```dart
var newMap = Map.fromIterables(sortKeysSomehow(oldMap.keys), newValues);
```

If you want to update the values *in place*, you can do:

```dart
var i = 0;
for (var key in map.keys) map[key] = newValues[i++];
```

or

```dart
var i = 0;
map.updateAll((k,v) => newValues[i++]);
```

Comment: Yeah that is even better. Nice.